# MiniKanren support by Dr Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, minikanren, reasoned-schemer

I started studying miniKanren with the book "The Reasoned Schemer - second edition" and the DrRacket scheme environment.

I installed the "faster-minikanren" package, but the first examples of the book with the command `run*` (for example, `(run* q #f)`) produce error messages such as `run*: bad syntax in: (run* q #f)`.

Does this mean that the "faster-minikanren" package does not provide the right definition of minikanren? Or am I making a mistake?

Comment: Racket has a lot of resources and tutorials available. This site isn't really a great place for tutorials, so you aren't going to get much traction here.

Comment: Can you include the full text of the definitions window program that you're using, including the #lang line and any requires?

Comment: Editor Window :    #lang racket
(require minikanren)
(run* q #f)      Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.12 [3m].
Language: racket, with debugging; memory limit: 128 MB.
. run*: bad syntax in: (run* q #f)

Comment: there's a close vote on this question as "off-topic" for "asking for recommendation for a book or a tool". I don't think this is right. The OP has already chosen the book and the package.

Answer (score 7):

As [the readme](https://github.com/michaelballantyne/faster-miniKanren) says, you need to put `(require minikanren)` in your Racket source file.

I've put in on the second line, after `#lang racket`, copied the `appendo` definition,

```
#lang racket
(require minikanren)

(define (appendo l s out)
  (conde
    [(== l '()) (== s out)]
    [(fresh (a d res)
       (== `(,a . ,d) l)
       (== `(,a . ,res) out)
       (appendo d s res))]))
```

then clicked on "Run", and tried this at the prompt:

```
> (run* (q r) (appendo q r '(1 2 3 4 5)))
'((() (1 2 3 4 5))
  ((1) (2 3 4 5))
  ((1 2) (3 4 5))
  ((1 2 3) (4 5))
  ((1 2 3 4) (5))
  ((1 2 3 4 5) ()))
>
```

Seems to be working. This didn't:

```
> (run* q #f)
. run*: bad syntax in: (run* q #f)

> (run* (q) #f)
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #f
  arguments...:
```

but this did:

```
> (run* (q) (lambda (_) #f))
'()
>
```

Comment: Hmm... the call (run* q #f) doesn't seem to be working, though... is that one working for you?

Comment: should it, though? I only have 1st ed. I'd expect at least `q` must be in parens: `(run* (q) ...)`. @JohnClements

Comment: I think I have a copy somewhere, but it's not here... I tried a bunch of variants, and couldn't get anything similar to work. The #f seems to break things, and it's hard to imagine the OP would have made that up.

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at the first few pages of the 2nd ed on Amazon, and in fact, it looks like the given example uses (run* q #u) ... which also doesn't work. The #u syntax would require a reader extension, so I'm guessing a bunch of adapting is required. It would be great if there was a companion for the pkg that helps users of the book.

Comment: Your example works fine  but it is not the case for the examples of the book "The Reasoned Schemer - second edition".

Comment: In the book q is not in parenthesis.

Comment: Right I changed #u for #f but it did not help.

Comment: @Schemer you can use the code that works, it should be easy to change the new (apparently, unsupported by this package) code to the old ways. this little snag shouldn't stop you. :) if you have trouble translating the examples, don't hesitate to ask on SO, with the specifics included (like you did here, so, kudos for that!).

Comment: @WillNess I will do so ! Thank You

Answer (score 6):

Okay, everything Will Ness says is correct. Let me add another high-level comment: it looks like there's a combination of further development and a certain lack of support that's contributing to your situation.

1) It looks like the minikanren language has continued to evolve since the book was published.

2) It looks like certain changes (e.g. the #u success goal) weren't easy fits for Racket (though they'd certainly be possible with a Reader extension), and the authors of the libraries you're using elected to change the language instead.

One thing that may help are the docs for the original minikanren package (online at https://docs.racket-lang.org/minikanren/index.html ), which are nicely formatted and readable, and provide references for further reading.

Comment: The new book explains that it covers 5 categories of changes . language, implementation, Laws, Commmandments and Translation.

Comment: I'm confused. Is there a new edition of the book? I can't quite make sense of your comment.

Comment: Yes, there is now a Second Edition of  "The Reasoned Schemer" based on an evolutpion of MiniKanren as a relational langage implemented in Scheme.

Comment: Hmm... I think I *was* looking at the second edition, using Amazon's "look inside", and it appeared to me that the first example in the book was still (run q #u)... but, full disclaimer, I probably didn't read the front material carefully enough. Is there mention of this problem in the front matter of the book?

Answer (score 4):

You may find the code from the second edition we just released helpful:

https://github.com/TheReasonedSchemer2ndEd/CodeFromTheReasonedSchemer2ndEd

Hope this helps!

Cheers,

--Will

Answer (score 1):

After installing `faster-minikanren` (through the package manager or `raco`), put the following snippet at the beginning of your file:

```lisp
#lang racket
(require minikanren)
(define succeed (== #t #t)) ;; suggested as per the footnote in frame 6 of Chapter 1, #s is written "succeed"
(define fail (== #f #t)) ;; and #u is written fail
(run* (q) succeed) ;; evaluates to '(_.0)
```