# Simple Prolog to Clojure core.logic

Tags: prolog, clojure-core.logic, minikanren

I've been playing with Prolog recently and getting my head around how to represent some tasks I want to do with it, which are largely about having a database of facts and doing simple queries on it, joining multiple facts together.

But I want to use this is in a context where I'm writing Clojure. And it seems like [core.logic](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic) should do what I want.

But I'm naively finding it difficult to see how to put basic Prolog predicates into core.logic.

For example, how should I represent something as simple as this in core.logic :

```
person(phil).
person(mike).
food(cheese).
food(apple).
likes(phil,apple).
likes(phil,cheese).
```

And a query like

```
food(F),person(P),likes(P,F)
```

Most introductions I can find are heavy on the logic programming but not the data representation.

Comment: Have you looked at the [tests](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/blob/master/src/test/clojure/clojure/core/logic/tests.clj) posted with core.logic? more [tests](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/blob/master/src/test/clojure/clojure/core/logic/pldb/tests.clj)  If this is acceptable, I can make it an answer so that others can see this question has an accepted answer.

Comment: Ok, so using db-rel and db?

Comment: There's no equivalent of Prolog’s defining relations and data at the same time?

Comment: Oops. Forgot to mention I have never used Clojure. I was writing an answer and the facts looked easy, but the the query has me confused on how to convert to *core.logic* so I will not be posting an answer.

Comment: Another way that might work for you would be to use [SWI-Prolog](https://www.swi-prolog.org/) and Java interface [JPL](https://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/Java.html). Another tool I am aware of but have not used.

Comment: Also noticed that `core.logic` is based on [minikanren](http://minikanren.org/) which might be of use.

Comment: Also found [this](http://mullr.github.io/micrologic/literate.html) which appears to explain how to convert *Prolog* to *minKranren* for use with *core.logic*

Comment: in [Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50568981/849891), I can just ``(define (person n)
  (conde
    [(== n 'phil)]
    [(== n 'mike)]))

(define (food n)
  (conde
    [(== n 'cheese)]
    [(== n 'apple)]))

(define (likes n x)
  (conde
    [(== n 'phil) (== x 'apple)]
    [(== n 'mike) (== x 'cheese)]))

(define (test)
  (run* (q)
     (fresh (a b) (== q `(,a ,b))
        (likes a b))))`` and running `(test)` produces `'((phil apple) (mike cheese))`. if you know of any readily avilable online environment where one could try the clojure core.logic code, I could try it there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Guy Coder said, the PLDB package under core.logic solves exactly this kind of problems:

```
(db-rel person p)
(db-rel food f)
(db-rel likes p f)

(def facts (db
  [person 'phil]
  [person 'mike]
  [food 'cheese]
  [food 'apple]
  [likes 'phil 'apple]
  [likes 'phil 'cheese]))

(with-db facts (run* [p f] (food f) (person p) (likes p f)))

=> ([phil cheese] [phil apple])    p=phil,f=cheese   or   p=phil,f=apple
```